# Dynamic *ngIf template

Tags: angularjs

Would like to show dynamic data using *ngIf and ng-template.  For example I would to display the title 'List of courses' if courses.length > 0 or No courses yet when courses.length == 0

So far, I have my

courses.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="courses.length > 0; then coursesList else noCourses">
    <ng-template #coursesList>
        List of courses
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #noCourses>
        No courses yet
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

my app.component.html

```
<app-ng-if-courses [courses]="courses"></app-ng-if-courses>
```

my ng-if-courses.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ng-if-courses',
  templateUrl: './ng-if-courses.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ng-if-courses.component.css']
})
export class NgIfCoursesComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('courses') courses = [];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

my app.component.ts

```
import { } from './ng-if-courses/ng-if-courses.component';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Angular app';



  // <app-ng-if-courses> 
//    courses = [];//no courses
    courses = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];


}
```

I think it will be very simple but I am a learning AngularJS

Comment: your `ng-template`'s should be outside the `*ngIf` div

Comment: Thanks you were correct